# A question on proving the sequence is bounded above by 2

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I'm still struggling to fully understand induction. Could someone help me find a way to prove, using induction, that the sequence $$x_1=1$$ $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2x_n} + 1$$ is bounded above by 2; that is, prove that $x_{n}$ is less than or equal to 2 for every $n$ that is an element of the natural numbers.

Comment: Do you mean $x_{n+1}=(1/2x_n)+1$? It appears that you neglected to hit the shift key.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, it is actually easier to prove simultaneously that $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ is bounded both above by $2$ and below by $1$.

An induction proof has two steps: first show that the theorem is true for $n=1$, and then, given that the theorem is true for some value of $n$, show that it is true for $n+1$.

The first part is easy for your problem: $x_1 = 1$ and $1 \le 1 \le 2$, so the theorem is true for $n=1$.

For the second part, assume that $1\le x_n \le 2$. Then, $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2x_n}+1$. Now, since $\frac{1}{2\cdot1} + 1 = \frac32$, and $\frac{1}{2\cdot2}+1=\frac54$, and $f(x) = \frac{1}{2x}+1$ is monotonically decreasing on $[1,2]$, $\frac54 \le x_{n+1} \le \frac32$, so $1 \le x_{n+1} \le 2$, and so the theorem is true for $n+1$, and, by induction, for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$.